# NetBeans is not working

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Netbeans working fine ,suddenly this error occurs package org.jdesktop doesnt exist

[image: Netbeans working fine ,suddenly this error occurs package org.jdesktop doesnt exist]

Comment: missing jar/library...

Comment: can you show us a snap of the projects' hierarchy?

Comment: but why happens suddenly ,before it works fine , now reinstalling ,let me update

Comment: Your Netbeans is fine. You need to to add the concerned JAR to your project.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question. The OP has included all needed details and explained that it just stopped working. This is a known error in Netbeans 7.

Answer (score 1):

If this worked and stopped working without any reason, stop netbeans and go to:

C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\NetBeans

and delete the Cache folder.

This error does not happen anymore in the latest netbeans version, or at least not that frequently.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing the jar [file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbsaf19jar.htm). Add the jar in your project properties. Hope this will solve your problem.